# how to use results from database in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

HOW TO LOAD THE CONTENT FROM  '.$user['Content'].'  in text field? 
if there are any solutions please help me

thank you

```
           $('#add-max').ready(function(){

            $.gritter.add({

           // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification

            title: 'This is a notice with a max of 3 on screen at one time!',
            // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification

            text: 'HERE ',
            // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
            image: 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/59268975/jquery_avatar_bigger.png',
            // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
            sticky: false,
            // (function) before the gritter notice is opened
            before_open: function(){
                if($('.gritter-item-wrapper').length == 3)
                {
                    // Returning false prevents a new gritter from opening
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: where is your ajax code? and relevant php code? if you don't have these, you can't get data to your page using jquery.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut  i dont have the ajax code, if i use $user['Content'] in another place than javascript code it works.

Comment: please edit your question and add that along with other relevant php code

Comment: @VolkanUlukut what is wrong in my question?? leave it ... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this in your PHP view / output file:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
       <!-- content -->

       <!-- assign js vars from PHP here -->
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var userContent = <?php echo $user['Content']; ?>
       </script>

       <!-- load your other custom JS files after. Best practice is to put these at the bottom of <body> -->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/your/javascript/file/here.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Basically you declare a javascript variable in an arbitrary javascript tag block, and echo your PHP data into that variable.

Then all subsequent scripts will have access to that variable and you can use it however you like.

So then to use your jQuery code, you would place the userContent variable you defined earlier, as the value for the `text` field.

```
       $('#add-max').ready(function(){

        $.gritter.add({

       // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification

        title: 'This is a notice with a max of 3 on screen at one time!',
        // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification

        text: userContent,
        // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
        image: 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/59268975/jquery_avatar_bigger.png',
        // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just sit there
        sticky: false,
        // (function) before the gritter notice is opened
        before_open: function(){
            if($('.gritter-item-wrapper').length == 3)
            {
                // Returning false prevents a new gritter from opening
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Hello , Thank for your answer, but this didnt work, ive did as you say and it doesnt load , in page source var userContent = <?php echo $user['Content']; ?> it looks ok, i receive what i want from db but when i use userContent in text field it doesnt show anything.

Comment: Ive made it, i get $user['Content'] into a div that ive hide it and then i declare 
 var userContent = $( "div.content" ).text()  and now its work:) thank for your help